# An error occurred (InvalidSubnet) when calling the CreateLoadBalancer operation: The subnet ID 'MythicalMysfitsCoreStack:PublicSubnetOne' is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-deployment, aws-fargate

Following the aws tutorial to deploy a dynamic website with Fargate:

In the step when we are going to create the Load Balancer with the command:

```
aws elbv2 create-load-balancer --name mysfits-nlb --scheme internet-facing --type network --subnets MythicalMysfitsCoreStack:PublicSubnetOne MythicalMysfitsCoreStack:PublicSubnetTwo > ~/environment/nlb-output.json
```

I get the error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidSubnet) when calling the CreateLoadBalancer operation: The subnet ID 'MythicalMysfitsCoreStack:PublicSubnetOne' is not valid
```

Before this step I have registered successfully the task definition and I am taking the names for the public subnets from the file */cloudformation-core-output.json* generated previously:

```
            {
                "Description": "REPLACE_ME_PUBLIC_SUBNET_ONE", 
                "ExportName": "MythicalMysfitsCoreStack:PublicSubnetOne", 
                "OutputKey": "PublicSubnetOne", 
                "OutputValue": "subnet-037a7c070431622b9"
            }, 
            {
                "Description": "REPLACE_ME_PUBLIC_SUBNET_TWO", 
                "ExportName": "MythicalMysfitsCoreStack:PublicSubnetTwo", 
                "OutputKey": "PublicSubnetTwo", 
                "OutputValue": "subnet-06b3c0d22d6bc3fad"
            }
```

Does anyone has an idea of what may be generating this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the "OutputValue" instead of the "ExportName" from the JSON file, I think you'll find it will work as expected.

```
aws elbv2 create-load-balancer --name mysfits-nlb --scheme internet-facing --type network --subnets subnet-037a7c070431622b9 subnet-06b3c0d22d6bc3fad > ~/environment/nlb-output.json
```

Comment: Yes, Indeed. "OutputValue" is the correct field to use in the CLI commands. Many thanks.